# Mobile data toggle missing from Action Center in Windows 10 Technical Preview

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, cellular-data, action-center

I have updated my phone with the Windows 10 Technical Preview. But I noticed that the mobile data toggle that was added to Action Center in 8.1 is now gone.

Has anyone found a way to get it back?

**Edit:**

Software: Windows 10 Technical Preview for Phones

OS version: 99941.12498

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately they don't have this option in Windows 10 Technical Preview.

Best way to address this is to give feedback to Microsoft using Feedback App (Shortcut: Press Volume Down and the Power button at the same time).